# Orderby on an Iesi set

Tags: nhibernate

Is there any way to perform a Linq OrderBy on a column in an OrderedSet (Iesi.Collection) and get the output as an ordered set. There appears to be no way to convert between IOrderedEnumerable and ISet...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert it *after* the query:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> x = ...
OrderedSet<int> s = new OrderedSet<int>(x.ToArray());
```

Or wrap it in an extension method for convenience:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
  public static OrderedSet<T> ToOrderedSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> s) {
    return new OrderedSet<T>(s.ToArray());
  }
}

IOrderedEnumerable<int> x = ...
OrderedSet<int> s = x.ToOrderedSet();
```